# I need some help with SQL and constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know much about SQL at all, but I have a table and it has a unique key constraint which I can see in SSMS by expanding the Keys folder under my table. It makes one column, 'name', UNIQUE.

At the moment it's completely unique, but I need to change it so name is unique for a specific ID in another column, 'catflapID'. So names can be duplicated in the table but for each catflapID there can be no duplicates.

I know absolutely nothing of how to do this, and I need somehow to end up with a script that removes the existing constraint and adds my new constraint.

Any advice?

Comment: SQl-Server `ALTER TABLE`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Comment: And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx if you want to find out the CONSTRAINT's name so you can put it in your script.

Comment: Something like `ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT ConstraintName;`

Comment: Then add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(catflapID, name)`

Comment: When you do this you are changing an assumption upon which other people may have made decisions.  Spend some time looking through SQL objects to make sure there are no queries that depend on a statement like the following "SELECT @id = catflapID FROM table where name = 'fido'".  You are looking for anything that is expecting a single result, because you have just made it return multiple rows.  Some may compile and some may not (the query above will work, but won't always give what you want).   Situations like this are case studies on why to NOT embed SQL in applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test_table]') AND name = N'IX_test_table')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test_table] DROP CONSTRAINT [IX_test_table]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test_table] ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_test_table] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [c_name] ASC,
    [c_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: this looks great thanks, the current key is called UQ__CatFlap__86007E41267D1C7F which looks randomly generated, I'm not sure how to write a generic script to drop it if the key has a different name on other servers, what do you think?

Comment: For example you can obtain name of key in this way:

`select name from sysobjects 
where parent_obj = (select id from sysobjects where name = 'test_table') AND xtype = 'UQ'`

Comment: Use the script from Max's comment above and store name in a variable.  Inject that variable into a string whose value is Max's answer to the question, but substitute the variable for the object name.  Then, use sp_executesql (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx) to execute the string.  This is called "dynamic SQL" and is really the only general way to do what you want. This is why you should always name objects, especially when you have more than one production server.

Answer (score 0):

You should create complex unique constraint with both columns.

Remove existing constraint and execute this code (change "MyTable" name to actual table name)

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT MyConstraint2 UNIQUE (catflapID, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the foreign key in relation-table. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (catflapID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , ...)
CREATE TABLE table2 (ID INT PRIMARY KEY , catflapID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table1(catflapID))
```

catflapID in table1 is NOT NULL and PRIMARY KEY, so this field will be unique.
catflapID in Table2 is referenced from Table2, so it can contain values from Table1 only.

Answer (score 0):

To create new constraint

```
ALTER TABLE tab
  ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueNameForCat UNIQUE (catflapID, name);
```

To drop the old, obsolete constraint

```
ALTER TABLE tab DROP CONSTRAINT oldConstraintName;
```